# PHP form submission using jQuery not working inside a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following function which returns data of users.

```
function returnChild(){
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM children
                         INNER JOIN districts ON children.ch_district = districts.dst_id
                         INNER JOIN states ON districts.dst_state = states.st_id
                         ORDER BY children.ch_id DESC");
  $stmt-> execute();

  $html = '<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
              <h2>List of Children <a href="#" class="action btn btn-dark pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pickupDetailsModal">+ Add New</a></h2>
                <div class="mt-4">
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Sex</th>
                      <th>Date of Birth</th>
                      <th>Father\'s Name</th>
                      <th>Mother\'s Name</th>
                      <th>State</th>
                      <th>District</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>';
  while($f = $stmt->fetch()){
    $html .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$f['ch_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.ucfirst($f['ch_sex']).'</td>
                <td>'.date('jS M, Y', strtotime($f['ch_dob'])).'</td>
                <td>'.$f['ch_father'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['ch_mother'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['st_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['dst_name'].'</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <span class="text-info pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#childUpdate"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <form method="post" action="processes/child.php">
                        <input type="hidden" value="delete" name="type" class="type">
                        <input type="hidden" value="'.$f['ch_id'].'" name="id">
                        <button type="submit" class="btnAction no-btn text-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <tr>
                  // THIS FORM IS NOT WORKING
                  <form method="post" action="processes/child.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="update" name="type" class="type">
                    <input type="hidden" value="'.$f['ch_id'].'" name="id">
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="'.$f['ch_name'].'"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sex" value="'.ucfirst($f['ch_sex']).'"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" value="'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f['ch_dob'])).'"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="father" value="'.$f['ch_father'].'"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mother" value="'.$f['ch_mother'].'"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" value="'.$f['st_name'].'"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="district" value="'.$f['dst_name'].'"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btnAction btn btn-dark">Update</button></td>
                  </form>
                </tr>
              </tr>';
  }
  $html .= '</table></div></div></div>';
  $html .= returnAJAX();
  return $html;
}
```

returnAJAX() function:

```
function returnAJAX(){
  $html = '<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".btnAction").on("click", function(e){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var form = $(this).closest("form");
                var type = form.find(".type").val();
                var dataString = form.serialize();
                var url = form.attr("action");
                alert(dataString);
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType : "json",
                  url: url,
                  data: dataString,
                  cache: true,
                  beforeSend: function(){
                    $(".message").hide();
                    $(".overlay").show();
                  },
                  success: function(json){
                    $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                      $(".message").html(json.status).fadeOut();
                    }, 3000);
                    if(json.returnType == "states"){
                      $("#stateContent").html(json.content).fadeIn();
                    }else if(json.returnType == "districts"){
                      $("#districtContent").html(json.content).fadeIn();
                    }else{
                      $("#childContent").html(json.content).fadeIn();
                    }
                    $(".overlay").hide();
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".message").offset().top }, "slow");
                  }
                });
                return false;
              });
              $(".editContent").on("click", function(e){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $(".contentHidden").fadeToggle();
                $(".contentVisible").fadeToggle();
              });
            });
          </script>';
  return $html;
}
```

The problem is that the second form is not working. When I click on the `Update` button then the `alert(dataString)` returns nothing on the alert box. The alert box shows up but it's empty as shown in the screenshot below:

[VIEW SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZDHA.png)

However, it works perfect when I take it out of table tags (td, tr etc.) but not when it's in the above format. The first form is working perfectly fine. The second form is not detecting the form fields here. What seems to be the issue? What am I missing here? I am stuck in this since 2 hours without a solution.

Comment: I would not create JavaScript with HTML using PHP. You should just keep your JavaScript on a separate page that is actually JavaScript. It will be cached that way. But that is not your issue. You would need to `$('form').each(function(i, s){ $(s).sumbit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* do your ajax submission */ }); });` to prevent the page from reloading.

Comment: I'm hoping you know that PHP executes on the Server before it is sent to the Browser, so after an initial HTML page build, you want to use AJAX.

Comment: Hi , change `var form = $(this).closest("form")` to `var form = $(this).closest("tr").find('form');`  and try again .

Comment: @Swati I wanted to do the same as I just had a look at one of my oldest projects on how I did it earlier.. Just then saw you recommended the same... Thanks Swati :) By the way, your name reminds me of someone....!

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do in this line of code?

```
`  $(".contentHidden").fadeToggle();
```

I mean ... character '`'

In js, you can try

```
function actionUpdate(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    var type = form.find(".type").val();
    ///code of you
    return false;
  }
  function clickEditContent(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(".contentHidden").fadeToggle();
    $(".contentVisible").fadeToggle();
  }
```

In html, you write

```
<button type="submit" class="btnAction btn btn-dark" onclick="actionUpdate(event)">Update</button>
```

Comment: For the first part you asked about ' ` ' character, it was a mistake (typed by mistake when pasting on stack, not in original code). Hence, corrected in the question. For the solution, I will give a try.

Comment: tried your solution. not even firing the function on button click.

Comment: I have modified the answer. Try it again

Comment: Same as my original issue.. It's firing the function but not capturing the form fields just as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I can help you!